# Можно ли запустить для отладки сам компилятор gcc через gdb для отладки внесенных изменений в его исходный код?

Tags: c, gcc

Мне необходимо вносить изменения в одну из стандартных библиотек в gcc, а затем отслеживать результат этих изменений. Можно ли использовать отладчик gdb, чтобы запускать в нем для отладки компилятор gcc, с переданной в качестве параметров тестовой программой?

Comment: Почему нет? gcc такая же программа, как и все другие. Просто собираете debug верию gcc и запускаете ее в gdb. Вот тут есть интструкции https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebuggingGCC (не понял правда, зачем для отладки изменений в библиотеке запускать под gdb компилятор?)

Comment: Библиотеки обычно тупо линкуются к программе и все. А чаще, вообще линкуются динамически, т.е. gcc только проверяет, что все функции в наличии и пишет в файл наличие библиотеки, а собственно цепляется библиотека уже потом, при выполнении программы. Так что сложно представить, что изменения в библиотеке повлияют на поведение gcc и его надо будет отлаживать

Comment: @Mike, кстати, есть некоторые вещи в стандартной библиотеке, которые очень тесно связаны с компилятором (например std::typeid или std::initializer_list). Возможно в этом случае нужно ковырять не только библиотеки, но и сам компилятор.